# No room to unscrew kitchen faucet

Tags: kitchens, faucet

It's a pretty simple problem, but I couldn't find anything, maybe I'm searching for the wrong keywords.

There's no room no unscrew my kitchen faucet, even if I twist the spout along with it there's just not enough room for a full turn of neither, it was probably installed before the countertop.

[image]

I tried to unscrew the spout off but there's not enough room for that either...

Worth noting that I'm in a rented apartment and I have no tools, I wonder if I can solve with by bending it with some pliers or some other cheap tool I can buy.

The other faucet I'm substituting this one with is bendable so it fits fine

Edit: I can remove the ring but not sure if its enough, tried wiggling and pulling the spout but it won't come off, I'm also afraid to ruin the wall.

[image]

Comment: When it comes to a rental, always make sure you've got the landlord's approval before doing work. _Especially_ if you're considering bending the faucet. The landlord might expect to find the original faucet in place, even if the one you're planning on installing is nicer and an upgrade in every way.

Comment: Yup! Aware of the consequences

Comment: Try pulling the spout straight up. There are some tight fitting "O" rings in there that could be stuck in with some corrosion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks to me like the nut on the spout would turn independently of the spout itself. Put the faucet back in its original position and turn that nut while holding the spout stationary. See if you can thread that off and pull the spout out, then you'll be able to rotate the faucet body.

If that's not the case, it looks like you'd be able to find a position that would allow you to spin the spout, or a combination of positions as you turn it and the faucet body simultaneously.

Comment: I tried twisting both but there's just not enough room, not enough room to twist just the spout either.

Comment: @Mojimi you shouldn't have to rotate the whole spout - the fixture itself should back straight off the pipe stub.

Comment: So I just yank it upwards after removing the ring?

Comment: That's what I would expect. There is probably an o-ring or other seal that will take some force to overcome.

Comment: That was it, just a bit of force

Answer (score 0):

Look on the photo. Just under the tap knob, I think I can see a ring that can be unscrewed to take the long outlet pipe off.

Comment: I can unscrew the ring but then what?

Comment: Nevermind it just needed a bit of force